# bootstrap 4 nav bar not covering full width when dropdown

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

This is what my code looks like for the nav bar, when I press the dropdown button, this is how it will look like on my page
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1gHsqAZ9QTaJX4A-1PXrVVoXi2KWBWqa6YTA_-QtG8wo/edit?usp=sharing

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-color mb-3">

  <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="/img/logo.png" alt="" width="100px" height="40px">RYCE</a>
  
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-white" href="/">HOME</a>
      </li>
      
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-white" href="">OUR CARS</a>
      </li>
      
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-white" href="">SHOP PARTS</a>
      </li>
      
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-white" href="">TEST DRIVE</a>
      </li>
      
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-white" href="">SERVICING</a>
      </li>
      
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-white" href="">SUPPORT</a>
      </li>
      
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-white" data-toggle="dropdown" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink">STAFF</a>
        
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <a href="/user/listuser" class="dropdown-item">Users Management</a>
          <a href="/booking/bookings" class="dropdown-item">Bookings Management</a>
          <a href="/product/products" class="dropdown-item">Products Management</a>
          <a href="/checkout/checkouts" class="dropdown-item">Orders Management</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-white" href=""><i style='font-size:24px' class='fas'>&#xf07a;</i></a>
      </li>
      
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-white" data-toggle="dropdown" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink"><i class="material-icons">&#xe853;</i></a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <a href="" class="dropdown-item">LOGIN</a>
          <a href="" class="dropdown-item">SIGN UP</a>
          <a href="" class="dropdown-item">PROFILE</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I have tried changing the width of the navbar and some of the bootstrap properties but none of my attempts have worked so far. I am unsure if the problem lies with the navbar or dropdown menu.

Thank you so much for all your inputs!

Comment: The link to the screenshot requires access, make it open.

Also title says bootstrap 3 but it's tagged as bootstrap 4 -- which is it? Code looks like bootstrap 4.

And lastly, try give a working sample as either a code snippet in Stack Overflow or a 3rd party service

Comment: @Simp4Code sorry bout that! stack overflow edited my post by itself, i have made some changes for now! The docs should be accessible now

Comment: I've posted an answer below with a working snippet, also fixed up your responsive menu issue (you had to change the ID)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `.dropdown-menu-right` to `.dropdown-menu` to align the dropdown to the right when it is shown -- this way it stops it from increasing the width of the page. Is this what you wanted?

Otherwise consider using Bootstrap collapse, I can change my example if you want!

```css
body { height: 100vh }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="bg-dark h-100">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-danger bg-color mb-3">

    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="/img/logo.png" alt="" width="100px" height="40px"> RYCE</a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="/">HOME</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="">OUR CARS</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="">SHOP PARTS</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="">TEST DRIVE</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="">SERVICING</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="">SUPPORT</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-white" data-toggle="dropdown" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink">STAFF</a>

          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
            <a href="/user/listuser" class="dropdown-item">Users Management</a>
            <a href="/booking/bookings" class="dropdown-item">Bookings Management</a>
            <a href="/product/products" class="dropdown-item">Products Management</a>
            <a href="/checkout/checkouts" class="dropdown-item">Orders Management</a>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white" href=""><i style='font-size:24px' class='fas'>&#xf07a;</i></a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-white" data-toggle="dropdown" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink"><i class="material-icons">&#xe853;</i></a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
            <a href="" class="dropdown-item">LOGIN</a>
            <a href="" class="dropdown-item">SIGN UP</a>
            <a href="" class="dropdown-item">PROFILE</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```